# Make delete confirmation modal using PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a delete button in a data table like this:

```
 <div class="card mb-3" style="width:70%;">
      <div class="card-header">
        <i class="fas fa-table"></i>
       Perusahaan</div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Kode Perusahaan</th>
                <th>Nama Perusahaan</th>
                <th>Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
             <?php
                $conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","penggajian");
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM perusahaan";
                $getperusahaan = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                while($list = mysqli_fetch_array($getperusahaan, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                echo "<tr><td>";
                echo $list['kode'];
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $list['nama'];
                echo "</td><td>";
                ?>
                <button type="button" data-id="<?php echo $list['id_perusahaan']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm passingID" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editperusahaan"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i> Edit</button></a>
                <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#konfirmasi" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete" style="margin-left: 10px;"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i> Delete</button>
                </td></tr>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```

when i click the delete button i want to make a confirmation on a bootstrap modal, before the user can delete it. This is my modal:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="konfirmasi" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Konfirmasi Penghapusan Data</h5>
          <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">Hapus Data?</div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <a href="hapusperusahaan.php?id=<?php echo $list['id_perusahaan'];?>" class="btn btn-danger" href="logout.php">Hapus</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The problem is that i don't know how to passed the `$list['id']` from the data table to my modal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace this  in your table list

```
   <button data-id="<?php echo $list['id'];?>" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#konfirmasi" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete-button" style="margin-left: 10px;"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i> Delete</button>
```

Replace this in your modal popup HTML

```
<a data-id="" class="btn btn-danger confirm-delete">Hapus</a>
```

Add javascript code

```
$('.delete-button').on('click', function (e) {
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
 $('.confirm-delete').attr('data-id',id);

});
$(".confirm-delete").on('click', function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    console.log(id);
    location.href="hapusperusahaan.php?id="+id;
});
```

for test 
http://jsfiddle.net/b8m03kjr

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove">Delete</button>
```

//delete.php

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
//Connect DB
$conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","penggajian");
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// sql to delete a record
$sql = "DELETE FROM perusahaan WHERE id = $id"; 
echo"sucess message";
```

//js

```
$(".remove").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).parents("tr").attr("id");
 if(confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?'))
    {
        $.ajax({
           url: '/delete.php',
           type: 'GET',
           data: {id: id},
           error: function() {
              alert('Something is wrong');
           },
           success: function(data) {
                $("#"+id).remove();
                alert("Record deleted successfully");  
           }
        });
    }
});
```